# How can i turn a few Planes upside down?

Tags: modeling

Im currently modeling a 3D Character in Blender. Im learning from a Video Tutorial Serires of Darrin Lile on Youtube, because im a total Blender Noob. I finished the surface of my Character using Planes. But now half if my Blender figure is covered in Shadows/Dark (?). Its really hard to describe that, especially when youre not a native speaker so here are some screenshots.[image]
[image]

PLS HELP. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Some of your Normals are reversed. <kbd>TAB</kbd> into Edit Mode select everything <kbd>A</kbd> In the Tool Bar go to Shading/UV's and under Normals choose Reclaculate.